# WebDriverIO: scrollIntoView action scrolls element outside Viewport?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, webdriver-io

I am using WebDriverIO (`"webdriverio": "^7.14.1"`). Usually the action `scrollIntoView()` works as expected. But sometimes, it scrolls the element outside of viewport, for example, it scrolls element to the top of the page hidden/out of view by one line (I hope you understand the point).

Right now, it happens to me like 50/50 all the time, so my tests are not stable because of this.

```
await $('#licenseName').scrollIntoView();
```

Any suggestion to overcome this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am able to fix this problem by using `scrollIntoViewOptions`, as below:

```
await $('#licenseName').scrollIntoView({block:'center'});
```

The element is scrolled into the center of the screen, hence always in the viewport.

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right, it is happening %80 percent time for me, I was hoping your solution help, but no. I will check and try other scrollIntoView options, I think there are more, may help me with my troubleshooting, best

Comment: @greenridinghood , maybe you can another argument, for example: `{block: 'center', inline: 'center'}` . I also need to use `inline` in some cases.